# How can I use SharedPreferences between different activities?

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I am having problems on using SharedPreferences in different activities and the XML file is no created (and I don't know why).

I'm using SharedPreferences in two activities:

- Here is the first one, where I just need to read the file:

  ```
   TextView screenCurrency = findViewById(R.id.dollar);

  preferences = getSharedPreferences("UserPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  if(preferences.contains("currency")){

      screenCurrency.setText(preferences.getString("currency","defect_currency"));

      if(preferences.getString("currency","defect_currency").equals("USD")){

          screenCurrency.setText("$");

      } else if(preferences.getString("currency","defect_currency").equals("EUR")){

          screenCurrency.setText("€");

      }
  } else {

      screenCurrency.setText("$");
  }
  ```
- This one is the other activity, where I read user preferences and I need to save them and include them in SharedPreferences:

  ```
   //get user preferences
  Spinner spinnerCurrency = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCurrency);
  Spinner spinnerRefresh = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerRefresh);

  currency = spinnerCurrency.getSelectedItem().toString();
  refresh = spinnerRefresh.getSelectedItem().toString();

  Button saveButton = findViewById(R.id.saveChangesButton);

  saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {



          preferences=getSharedPreferences("UserPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

          editor.putString("currency",currency);

          editor.putString("refresh",refresh);



      }
  });
  ```

Anyone knows what is wrong?

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values

Comment: what are the values you are saving against variables name currency and refresh?

Comment: I think you're missing editor.commit(); after putting values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Answer (score 0):

change your code

```
   preferences = getSharedPreferences("UserPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String currency = preferences.getString("currency",null)
    if(currency.contains("currency")){
```

Comment: i missed null value please check edited code and use editor.commit(); while saving into sharedprefrence

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing editor.commit(); after putting values

```
 //get user preferences
Spinner spinnerCurrency = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCurrency);
Spinner spinnerRefresh = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerRefresh);

currency = spinnerCurrency.getSelectedItem().toString();
refresh = spinnerRefresh.getSelectedItem().toString();

Button saveButton = findViewById(R.id.saveChangesButton);

saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {



        preferences=getSharedPreferences("UserPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString("currency",currency);

        editor.putString("refresh",refresh);

        editor.commit();


    }
});
```

Comment: I missed it but It was not the cause because it is still not working.. :(

Comment: can you check value returned by editor.commit();? Is it true or false?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sharedPreferences for activities then you must use
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myinfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);